# Run function automatically in a struct

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a Firebase fetch function which calls a variable called Dowkg. With a button this works just perfectly to call the `func firestoreManager.fetchWeight()`.

But how can I call the function automatically when the View is loaded and not with the button ? I don't want to push the button it just has to be automatic.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var firestoreManager: FirestoreManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                firestoreManager.fetchWeight()
            } label: {
                Text("Fetch Data")
                
            }
            Text("Number: \(firestoreManager.Dowkg)")
        }
    } }

  struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView()
            .environmentObject(FirestoreManager())
    } }
```

Comment: What about leveraging an @ObservedObject or an init() which calls `fetchWeight()`     within the View to populate the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI gives us equivalents to UIKit’s viewDidAppear() and viewDidDisappear() in the form of onAppear() and onDisappear(). You can attach any code to these two events that you want, and SwiftUI will execute them when they occur.

Whenever the view appears the onAppear block is called and when disappears onDisappear is called so call your function inside on appear block.
There is another function that is onChange which called when some changes made on view after appear

```
  struct ChildView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var firestoreManager: FirestoreManager
    
       
    var body: some View {
  
        VStack {
           
            Button {
                firestoreManager.fetchWeight()
               } label: {
                Text("Fetch Data")
               }
             Text("Number: \(firestoreManager.Dowkg)")
            }
          .onAppear {
                firestoreManager.fetchWeight()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("ChildView disappeared!")
            }

    } 
}
```